# Зачем нужен GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: hibernate

Не могу понять зачем нужен GenerationType.SEQUENCE и как им пользоваться?
Можно минимальное объяснение с примером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это специальная тип для генерации значений из последовательности. Создаете в базе данных, которая их поддерживает (например, Postgres):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq START WITH 100000;
```

Используете в качестве генератора:

```
public class My {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "my_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;
}
```

---

`allocationSize` указывает Hibernate сколько нужно резервировать значений из последовательности за одно обращение к базе данных. В данном случае на каждое обращение - 1 раз. Чем больше, тем сильнее снижается нагрузка на базу данных, но больше расходуется последовательность (иногда впустую)

Comment: В чем выигрыш от этого? Что такое allocationSize = 1?

Comment: allocationSize указывает Hibernate сколько нужно резервировать значений из последовательности за одно обращение к базе данных. В данном случае на каждое обращение - 1 раз. Чем больше, тем сильнее снижается нагрузка на базу данных.

Comment: Дело не в выигрыше, а в поддерживаемых структурах в базе данных. Например, в Postgres не другого способа для автоинкремента (тип SERIAL автоматом тоже создает последовательность)

Comment: Получается: есть одна таблица -  последовательность, остальные таблицы в качестве PK используют значения из этой таблицы? Тогда разница между автоинкрментным ключом и ключом-последовательности какая?

Comment: Автоинкремент работает на уровне базы данных при вставке, а последовательность на уровне приложения (хотя в отдельных случаях может и на уровне базы данных по триггеру). В целом, последовательность более гибкая.